(Next.js + typescript)Using aws4.sign the POST request, and upload file via formData from web browser to S3
I was stuck on this bugs for weeks, thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.
I am trying to

Using aws4.sign() to sign a HTTP POST request at backend end.
Get the policy from yaml file, and construct S3policy manually.
Return the S3policy and signuare back to front end.
At front end, construct a formData, append attributes of policy, then POST to S3 end point.

Here are my codes:

Backend sign endpoints:



const policy: Policy | undefined = getPolicyByUuid(uuid);

  if (!policy) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: `Policy for uuid ${uuid} not found` },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const amzDate = currentDate.toISOString().replace(/[:\-]|\.\d{3}/g, "");
  const dateStamp = amzDate.substr(0, 8);

  const folderPath = `uploads/${policy.folderName}/`;
  const filePath = `${folderPath}${fileName}`;

  const s3policy = {
    expiration: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString(),
    conditions: [
      { bucket: bucketName },
      ["starts-with", "$key", folderPath],
      { acl: policy.acl },
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", fileType],
      { "x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274" },
      { "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256" },
      ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
      {
        "x-amz-credential": `${accessKeyId}/${dateStamp}/${region}/s3/aws4_request`,
      },
      { "x-amz-algorithm": policy.x_amz_algorithm },
      { "x-amz-date": amzDate },
    ],
  };

  const base64Policy = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(s3policy)).toString("base64");

  // const endpoint = `https://${bucketName}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${filePath}`;

  const endpoint = `https://${bucketName}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/`;

  const options = {
    service: "s3",
    region: region,
    method: "POST",
    path: `/${bucketName}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": fileType,
      "x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274",
      "x-amz-acl": policy.acl,
      "x-amz-credential": `${accessKeyId}/${dateStamp}/${region}/s3/aws4_request`,
      "x-amz-date": amzDate,
      Policy: base64Policy,
    },
  };

  aws4.sign(options, {
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
  });

  console.log("Options after sign: ", options);

  // Exclude 'Host' header from the response
  const signedHeaders = { ...options.headers };
  delete signedHeaders.Host;

  try {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        url: endpoint,
        signedHeaders: options.headers,
        key: filePath,
        acl: policy.acl,
        expiration: s3policy.expiration,
        "x-amz-credential": options.headers["x-amz-credential"],
        amzAlgorithm: policy.x_amz_algorithm,
        amzDate: amzDate,
        Policy: base64Policy,
        "x-amz-signature":
          options.headers["Authorization"].split("Signature=")[1],
      },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error generating signed URL:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ signedUrl: "error" }, { status: 500 });
  }




Then at front end, the upload codes are:



for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const fileName = files[i].name;
        const fileType = files[i].type;

        console.log(`Upload ${fileName} to S3`); // Print each file name

        
        const {
          data: {  url,
            signedHeaders,
            key,
            acl,
            expiration,
            'x-amz-credential': amzCredential,
            amzAlgorithm,
            amzDate,
            Policy,
            'x-amz-signature': amzSignature,}
        } = await axios.get(`/api/aws-sign`, {
          params: { userName, organization: ORG_NAME, fileName, fileType},
        });

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('key', key);
        formData.append('acl', acl);
        formData.append("success_action_status", "201");
        formData.append('Content-Type', fileType);
        formData.append('x-amz-meta-uuid', '14365123651274');
        formData.append("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256");
        formData.append('x-amz-credential', amzCredential);
        formData.append('x-amz-algorithm', amzAlgorithm);
        formData.append('x-amz-date', amzDate);
        formData.append('Policy', Policy);
        formData.append('x-amz-signature', amzSignature);
        formData.append('file', files[i]);

    
        const uploadResponse = await axios.post(url, formData, {
          headers: {
            ...signedHeaders,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 

          }
        });

        console.log('Upload response:', uploadResponse);



But I always get 400 Error codes from S3 service 'response: PRO FEATURE ONLY
Please help, I really don't know what is wrong with the codes. Thanks!
